# Types of objects in javaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I have a few objects (a,b,c,..i) in js created as shown below

```
var a = {x:1};
var b = function(y){this.x = y};
var c = new Object({x:1});
var d = new b(1);
var e = b(1);
var f = (y) => {return {x:y};};
var g = new f(1); // error
var h = f(1);
var i = new a();//error
```

Kindly explain what is the deference in these objects?
why some are invalid? 
I'm expecting an advanced explanation connected to prototypes in js.

Comment: If you read the error, you'd see `f is not a constructor`. So... there's that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant difference between the object returned on all the objects you create but the way you create they may differ. On other to you "new" keyword you have to call an constructor function:

```
function NewObject() {
    this.value = 0;
}
```

The constructor function is analogous to the class in other OO languages. The constructor  is an instance of Function an Object, an object created like this:

```
let x = {};
```

Is an instance of Object, but not of Function.